# Create a grouped bar chart with the groups being all the unique values of a dataframe column

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have the dataframe below and I want it to be displayed as a grouped bar chart as follows. In the `x axis` there should be the `year` while in the `y axis` count n. The complex thing is that I want the `severity` to be displayed as a grouped bar chart with a different color for every unique value of `severity` `(2,3,4)`.
something like:

[image]

```
library(plotly)
df2<-structure(list(year = c("2017", "2018", "2018", "2019", "2019", 
"2019", "2019", "2019", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020"
), severity = c("2", "3", "4", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "2", 
"3", "3", "3", "4"), accident.description = c("right lane blocked", 
"two lanes blocked", "road closed", "one lane blocked", "right lane blocked", 
"one lane blocked", "right lane blocked", "two lanes blocked", 
"right lane blocked", "right and center lane blocked", "right lane blocked", 
"two lanes blocked", "two lanes blocked"), n = c(3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), groups = structure(list(
    year = c("2017", "2018", "2018", "2019", "2019", "2020", 
    "2020", "2020"), severity = c("2", "3", "4", "2", "3", "2", 
    "3", "4"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4:5, 6:8, 9L, 
        10:12, 13L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L), .drop = TRUE))

fig <- plot_ly(df2, x = ~year, y = ~n, type = 'bar', name = 'severity',
               hovertext = paste(
                 "<br>Year :",
                 df2$year,
                 "<br>Severity :",
                 df2$severity,
                 "<br>Accident Description :",
                 df2$accident.description,
                 paste("<br> Count:"),
                 df2$n
               ),
               hoverinfo = "text")
fig
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `name = 'severity'` with `color =  ~severity` and you'll get this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We may do this by creating a `ggplot` object and then wrap with `ggplotly`

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

p <- df2 %>%
   ungroup %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = year, y = n, fill = severity)) +
   geom_col(position= "dodge") +
   theme_bw()

ggplotly(p)
```